# What's The Minimum Staffing/Logistics For Running A Hospital?

Tags: surgery, practice-of-medicine, medications, hospital, nurse-practitioner

Specifically, a hospital serving a local population of 200-400 people, and assuming departments include ER, ICU, dentistry, maternity, outpatient, pharmaceutical, radiology, and general surgery. What would the physician to nurse ratio be? Could a physician cross departments for efficiency (i.e. unused ICU staff doubling as GP for outpatients)? Money is of no concern, and administration is run by the physicians themselves.